# Pass object into react component using react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my routes.js, I have a problem passing data which has been received in `userProfiles`, to `userProfileDetail` of that user. I don't want to do another API call in `userProfileDetail`, because there is already a call in `userProfiles`

```
const routes = {
  component: Base,
  childRoutes: [
    {
      path: '/profiles',
      getComponent: (location, callback) => {
        callback(null, userProfiles);
      }
    },

    {
      path: '/profile/:profile_id',
      getComponent: (location, callback) => {
        callback(null, userProfileDetail);
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

How I navigate is just via a

`<Link to={`/profile/${user._id}`} />` in `userProfiles`, but how to pass from `userProfiles` to `userProfileDetail`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You must make another call

What if a person refreshes the page on `userProfileDetail`? how will the get any data at all? You cannot make assumptions about what data the user already has. you must make sure that any page can be built by itself.

## Use state management

A great way to share data across your app is to implement a state management system like `redux` that way you can call any data you have from any component in your app making passing data like this redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `state` of react-router.

Set an object to `to` prop in your Link like this.

```
<Link to={{
  pathname: `/profile/${user._id}`,
  state: { userProfiles: userProfiles }
}}/>
```

and now you can access this state from `location`.

```
location.state.userProfiles
```

Also, note that `state` won't have any value if user navigate the page by directly typing URL in the browser or reload the page. So the ideal solution is call API and load these data agian using the `user._id` if `state` has no value.